Use DataFrame with an imported excel file
I used the following code to import an Excel file into Python:
import pandas as pd

file_name = (file.direction)
ExcelData = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = "File Name", header = 0)
Data = ExcelData.head()

After this I do:
df = pd.DataFrame(Data)

My issue is that I want to make a linear regression model from the sklearn.linear_model class, and to do this I need to define the X and Y columns. The question is: With the way I imported the data, how can I reference the columns in the x and y variables? Right now I am doing the following:
X = df[["ColumnName1", "ColumnName2", "ColumnName3"]]
y = df["ColumnName4"]

If anyone knows how to get the columns into the x and y variables, I would greatly appreciate it :)

Data is already a DataFrame, so pd.DataFrame(Data) is a useless step. What do you think it does?

Why are you using ExcelData.head()? This will only retrieve the first 5 rows from the excel file. Don't you want to use all of the rows for the linear regression model?

I'm aware of the head() function, starting with only 5 rows to make sure that the data is being imported correctly, after that the head function will be removed. I did know that Data served as a data frame though, thanks for that.

You can reference the column variables by simply using their header names as given in the xlsx file.
You could try something like this:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel(r'You file name.xlsx')
X = df.drop(columns = ['the column name for the output'])
Y = df['the column name for the output']
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
model.predict(<Your X inputs>)

If you have any categorical variables, i recommend one hot encoding your data using from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder before sending it to the Linear regression model. This is because all data needs to be in a numerical format. Hope this helps

This is what I needed thanks, I was missing the df.drop() function to import specific columns. Thanks!

To use the "fit" method from scikit-learn linear_model you can use directly a pandas DataFrame to the X vector and a pandas Series to your y.
It should work and you can use the code below as base:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0,1,2], 'col2': [0.5,1.5,2.5], 'col3': [1,2,3]})

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

X = my_df[['col1','col2']]
y = my_df['col3']

reg.fit(X, y)
reg.coef_

